# Having trouble reading the images using open cv

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, opencv, image-recognition

I have a folder name "seg_train" in which I have 6 labeled folders: building, tree, street, glacier, forest, sea and mountain. I am trying to read all the images in these folders using open `cv` and for that I have written a function but I don't know what I am doing wrong. There are approximately 14000 files in these 6 folders all together but the function I wrote is reading only 2300 from one folder. Could you please help?
Here's the python code

> result- Shape of Images: (2382, 150, 150, 3)
>
> Shape of Labels: (2382,)
>
> i was expecting (14000,150,150,3)

```
for image_file in os.listdir(r'C:/Users/dhvan/Desktop/intel-image-classification/seg_train/seg_train/'+ labels):
    image = cv2.imread(r'C:/Users/dhvan/Desktop/intel-image-classification/seg_train/seg_train/' + labels + r'/'+ image_file)
    image = cv2.resize(image,(150,150))
    
    Images.append(image)
    Labels.append(label)
return shuffle(Images,Labels,random_state=812490023)
```

Comment: Can you share your code? See: [mcve].

Comment: what is the value of the variable labels in your for loop? You need to iterate this code over all the labels so can make sure that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the code below. Also I think if you try to read in 14000 images of size (150,150,3) you will get a resource exhaust error because this will use a very large amount
of memory. If you are building a CNN classifier I recommend you read the images in in batches using the Keras ImageDataGenerator.flowfrom directory, documentation is here
https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/

```
import os
dir=r'C:/Users/dhvan/Desktop/intel-image-classification/seg_train/seg_train'
path_to_labels=os.path.join (dir, 'labels')
dir_list=os.listdir(path_to_labels)
for images in dir_list:
    path_to_images=os.path.join (path_to_labels, images)
    cv2.imread(path_to_images)
```